# Generar imagen php

Tags: php, html

Estoy teniendo problemas para generar una imagen desde PHP. Mi problema es que se genera el archivo perfectamente con la estructura que necesito, pero al abrir el archivo de imagen aparece el siguiente mensaje: "Parece que el formato de este archivo no es compatible." Lo estoy realizando con Laravel

Adjunto código de como genero la imagen y la guardo en la BD (el nombre de la imagen)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="card-header">Firma</div>
    <input type="color" class="js-color-picker  color-picker">
    <input type="range" class="js-line-range" min="1" max="72" value="1">
    <label class="js-range-value">1</label>Px
    <canvas class="js-paint paint-canvas" id="canvas" name="firma" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function crearPaciente(Request $request){

    $nombre = $request->get('nombre');
    $apellidos = $request->get('apellidos');
    $dni = $request->get('dni');
    $fechaNacimiento = $request->get('fechaNacimiento');
    $lugarNacimiento = $request->get('lugarNacimiento');
    $direccion = $request->get('direccion');
    $codigoPostal = $request->get('codigoPostal');

    $telefonoFijo = $request->get('telefonoFijo');
    $telefonoMovil = $request->get('telefonoMovil');
    $compania = $request->get('compania');

    

    //obtenemos la fecha de firma
    $fecha = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $fechaFinal = $fecha->toDateString();

    $firma = $request->get('dataURL');

    $this->generateImage($firma, $nombre, $apellidos);

    $pacienteFirma = $nombre.$apellidos.".png";

    $guardarFirma = str_replace(' ', '', $pacienteFirma);

    
    $data = array('nombre'=>$nombre,
                  "apellidos"=>$apellidos,
                  "dni"=>$dni,
                  "fecha_nacimiento"=>$fechaNacimiento,
                  "lugar_nacimiento"=>$lugarNacimiento,
                  "direccion"=>$direccion,
                  "cod_postal"=>$codigoPostal,
                  "tlf1"=>$telefonoFijo,
                  "tlf2"=>$telefonoMovil,
                  "compania"=>$compania,
                  );

    $consentimiento = array('fechaFirma' => $fechaFinal,
                            'firma' => $guardarFirma
                           );


    \DB::table('pacientes')->insert($data);
    \DB::table('lopds')->insert($consentimiento);
```

**Capturo el resquest del canvas**

```
$firma = $request->get('dataURL');

$this->generateImage($firma, $nombre, $apellidos);
```

Función "generateImage"

```
public function generateImage($img, $nombre, $apellidos){

    $cadenaNombre = $nombre.$apellidos;
    
    $nombreApellidos = str_replace(' ', '', $cadenaNombre);

    $path = "images/".$nombreApellidos.".png";
    
    $imgTran1 = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $imgTran2 = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($imgTran2);

    $success = file_put_contents($path, $data);
}
```

Tengo que decir, que antes de transformar la imagen, la cadena resultante del canvas es una cadena en base64, como se puede ver en la variable $imgTran1.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda, ya que no se que puede estar fallando para que no se muestre la imagen. Al devolverla en html de nuevo, tampoco se muestra.

Un saludo y gracias de nuevo

Comment: Entonces el problema puede venir desde que generas la imagen en _canvas_ y la codificas en _base64_. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar ese código.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya lo he editado. la variable $firma que contiene el request es una cadena en base64 en la función generateImage transformo (SUPUESTAMENTE).

Comment: Puedes abrir el archivo generado y revisar si efectivamente contiene datos. de otro modo cambia a `base64_decode($imgTran2, true)` para que haga un chequeo estricto del contenido (si es incorrecto, la salida sera vacía).

Comment: si, si el string de base64 lo abro en el navegador, se muestra la iamgen perfectamente.Voy a probar la función

Comment: Si uso la función como de dices @F.Igor me guarda el fichero, si la abro desde el windows, seguimos teniendo el mismo problema, sin embargo, si la abro desde el navegador, la imagen se ve en blanco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La imagen convertida se ha utilizado incorrectamente, en la segunda conversion/reemplazo se utiliza la misma imagen inicial (`$img`) como fuente, por lo que `data:image/png;base64` queda en la imagen final. (cambia `$img` por `$imgTran1`)

```
$imgTran1 = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$imgTran2 = str_replace(' ', '+', $imgTran1);
$data = base64_decode($imgTran2);
```

Comment: Efectivamente, gracias por la ayuda